# Erlang ets:select sublist

Tags: datatables, erlang, contains, ets

Is there a way in Erlang to create a select query on ets table, which will get all the elements that **contains** the searched text?

```
ets:select(Table,
  [{ %% Match spec for select query
      {'_', #movie_data{genre = "Drama" ++ '_' , _ = '_'}},  % Match pattern
      [],                                                    % Guard
      ['$_']                                                 % Result
  }]) ;
```

This code gives me only the data that **started** (=prefix) with the required text (text = "Drama"), but the problem is I need also the the results that contain the data, like this example:

> #movie_data{genre = "***Action, Drama***" }

I tried to change the guard to something like that -

`{'_', #movie_data{genre = '$1', _='_'}}, [string:str('$1', "Drama") > 0] ...`

But the problem is that it isn't a qualified guard expression.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. You need to design your data structure to be searchable by the guard expressions, for example:

```erlang
-record(movie_data, {genre, name}).
-record(genre, {comedy, drama, action}).

example() ->
    Table = ets:new('test', [{keypos,2}]),
    ets:insert(Table, #movie_data{name  = "Bean",
                                  genre = #genre{comedy = true}}),
    ets:insert(Table, #movie_data{name  = "Magnolia",
                                  genre = #genre{drama = true}}),
    ets:insert(Table, #movie_data{name  = "Fight Club",
                                  genre = #genre{drama = true, action = true}}),
    ets:select(Table,
               [{#movie_data{genre = #genre{drama = true, _ = '_'}, _ = '_'},
                 [],
                 ['$_']
                }]).
```

Comment: But say I want to see all Batman's movies, I'll need to search each time for the specific title...
So there is no way to do it, unless I will convert the ETS to list and use list comprehensions?

Comment: @OmerLux: Exactly.

Comment: So if I need to use lists, what is more efficient (in terms of memory and run time) to transfer in the argument of a function? 
A list or an ETS table?